# For continuous $f(x)$, if $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)/p(x)=0$ for every nonzero polynomial $p(x)$, then is the same true for nonzero analytic $p(x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, analytic-functions

Let $f(x)$ be a continuous real function on a neighborhood of 0 in $\mathbb{R}$.

Suppose $f(x)>0$ for $x\neq0$, and suppose $\lim_{x\to0} f(x)/p(x)$ for every nonzero polynomial $p(x)$.

My question is whether $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)/P(x) = 0$ for any $P(x)$ analytic at 0, and not identically zero (on some connected neighborhood of 0)?

---

My thinking so far is as follows:

1. It suffices to show $|P(x)|/f(x) \to \infty$ as $x\to 0$.
2. Similarly, by hypothesis, already $|p(x)|/f(x) \to \infty$ as $x\to 0$ for $p(x)$ any nonzero polynomial.
3. We are done if in the RHS of the expression
   $$
   \lim_{x\to0} P(x)/f(x) 
   = \lim_{x\to 0} \left( \frac{1}{f(x)}
        \lim_{n\to\infty} |P_n(x) |
   \right)
   =
   \lim_{x\to 0}
        \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{|P_n(x) |}{f(x)}
   $$
   we can interchange the two limits.

(Here $P_n(x)$ is the $n$th Taylor polynomial at $x=0$ of $P(x)$.)

Could anyone explain whether the changes (1) and (2) described in Step 3 above are justified? (Or, is my reasoning flawed?)

---

Edit: removed a question about a trivial step (the 2nd equality above).

Comment: What about $P(x) = e^{-x}$?

Comment: @GregMartin what is your proposal for $f$? As near as I can tell the OP's claim is true, since $f$ must have a zero of infinite order at the origin while any holomorphic function can have a zero of at most finite order so the limit just remain zero.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Oh I see, I overlooked the fact that the $\frac{1}{f(x)}$ factor can move inside the $n$ limit since it has no $n$ dependence to begin with

Comment: Indeed @Indraneel. Also, unless I'm missing something (*which may be possible, I haven't thought about it much... In particular, I didn't assume continuity, which I'm not sure is needed but would require some thought; positivity is definitely redundant though by continuity forcing the same sign locally around zero*), my prior comment should serve as an alternative proof of the result.

Comment: As to justifying interchanging the limits, I think it suffices to consider the remainder term in Taylor approximation (e.g. Cauchy estimates) and use it to bound the difference appropriately. More precisely, we know by Taylor's Theorem that the Taylor polynomial converge uniformly to the limit on compact subsets of the (open) disk of convergence, so just choose a small enough compact subset around zero and interchange your limit using uniformity.

Comment: Sorry I mistakenly thought the limits were at infinity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $P$ is analytic near zero, then we can write $P(z) = z^k g(z)$ for some analytic $g$ with $g(0) \neq 0$. Then ${f(z) \over P(z)} = {f(z) \over z^k} {1 \over g(z)}$ and hence the limit is zero.